# Drawing a mobius strip in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, geometry

I'm trying to draw a Mobius strip using parametric equation such that it is always 'lit' (i.e. all of the normal vectors point towards the camera).

The main problem that I have is that the mobius strip is not orientable, so however I orient the strip, some normal vectors are going to point away from the camera.  Is there a smart way to determine when to "flip" the normal vector such that it always points towards the camera?

I've tried drawing the mobius strip twice such that normals are in both direction, but I then I get black and white strips from z-fighting.

Comment: Have you considered turning off lighting or writing a shader to apply constant lighting by disregarding normals?

Comment: Good point, I want lighting to be on in this case.  I have a point light source, and I want parts of the strip to be darker than others based on its orientation, but never completely black.

Comment: Draw it twice, but enable backface culling `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); glCullFace(GL_BACK)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simple: Don't go from just 0 to 2π, but to 4π, i.e. you pass two times over the strip. Enable back face culling.

This is kind of the standard experiment on real world Möbius strips, drawing a line along the middle until you hit the beginning of the line. You have to go around the strip two times. It's exactly this, what you do with OpenGL then.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
glLightModeli( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE );
```

For two-sided lighting OpenGL will automatically flip the normal for backfacing triangles.

Comment: The 'back side' is now white.  Is there a way to make it the same color/lighting as the 'front side'?  This seems pretty cool though!

Comment: @jh314 The back side uses the material of the back side (assuming you're using the fixed function pipeline, as otherwise light model two-side wouldn't help anyway). Thus just call `glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, ...)` whereever you called `glMaterial(GL_FRONT, ...)` to set the same material for both sides.